# How could you make this UUID generator more efficient?

Tags: c++

I just coded the implementation of a UUID generator in C++ after the definition from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Format). I am intermediate in C++ programming and don't know all the tricks and best practices for this language. Any suggestions are welcome!

PS: I am also not sure how to display the char array as a hex string, like in `123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000`

```
// UUIDGenerator.cpp : Defines the functions for the static library.
//

#include "pch.h"
#include "framework.h"

const char* generateUUID()
{
    char uuid[16];
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto now_ms = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now);
    auto epoch = now_ms.time_since_epoch();
    auto value = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(epoch);
    long duration = value.count();

    unsigned int time_low = duration & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    unsigned short int time_mid = (duration >> 32) & 0xFFFF;
    // UUID Version 1
    unsigned short int time_hi_and_version = (duration >> 48) & 0xFFF | 0x1000;
    // UUID Variant 1
    unsigned short int clock_seq_hi_and_res = (duration >> 60) & 0x7FF | 0xa000;
    // Just some random 48 bit number instead of the MAC address
    unsigned long int node = 0x23F8E9B5550A;

    uuid[0] = time_low & 0xFF;
    uuid[1] = (time_low >> 8) & 0xFF;
    uuid[2] = (time_low >> 16) & 0xFF;
    uuid[3] = (time_low >> 24) & 0xFF;
    
    uuid[4] = time_mid & 0xFF;
    uuid[5] = (time_mid >> 8) & 0xFF;

    uuid[6] = time_hi_and_version & 0xFF;
    uuid[7] = (time_hi_and_version >> 8) & 0xFF;

    uuid[8] = clock_seq_hi_and_res & 0xFF;
    uuid[9] = (clock_seq_hi_and_res >> 8) & 0xFF;

    uuid[10] = node & 0xFF;
    uuid[11] = (node >> 8) & 0xFF;
    uuid[12] = (node >> 16) & 0xFF;
    uuid[13] = (node >> 24) & 0xFF;
    uuid[14] = (node >> 32) & 0xFF;
    uuid[15] = (node >> 40) & 0xFF;

    return uuid;
}
```

I have tried to include the library in the project I write this for, but it didn't work.

Comment: `I am also not sure how to display the char array as a hex string` - So, is your code working as intended or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tried to include the library in the project I write this for, but it didn't work.

You didn't specify what happens when you try to use it, but I would guess that the problem is that you're declaring the `uuid` array as a local variable so it becomes invalid when it goes out of scope of scope and using that array is undefined behavior. What actually happens in the end is platform dependent, but usually the local variable is stored in the function's stack-frame and when the function returns this stack-frame "destroyed" and that stack space will be used by other functions that are called, and they might overwrite the memory where `uuid` was.

You can return `uuid` by allocating memory for it with `new`, but the way I recommend doing it is to make the function receive an array as argument and write to it. You should also use `std::uint8_t` defined in `cstdint` instead of `char` because `char` is defined as 1 byte, but there are obscure platforms where 1 byte is not 8 bits, and `std::uint8_t` is guaranteed to be 8 bits. Though, if you think your code is never going to be used on those platforms, you shouldn't worry about that, it's reasonable to consider 1 byte as 8 bits. But another problem with `char` is that the standard does not define if it is signed or unsigned, so `char` may be equivalent to `signed char` instead of `unsigned char`, which isn't what you want when you're dealing with bits.

> I am also not sure how to display the char array as a hex string

You can do it with `std::hex`:

```
int main()
{
    std::uint8_t uuid[16]{};

    generateUUID(uuid);
    size_t n = 0;
    for (size_t i: {4, 2, 2, 2, 6}) {
        for (size_t j = n; j < n + i; ++j)
            std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << static_cast<unsigned>(uuid[j]);
        if (i == 6)
            std::cout << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << '-';
        n += i;
    }
}
```

It's calling `generateUUID` with an argument like I recommended and using `std::setw` to set the width of the output (2 characters for each byte) and `std::setfill` to set the fill character when the byte doesn't use 2 characters. I cast `uuid[j]` to avoid having the byte interpreted as a `char`

> How could you make this UUID generator more efficient?

By more efficient you mean significantly faster? I don't think you can, at least not in a way I can think of. I tried doing it with AVX on x86 but the code ended up having to do a lot more operations. Speaking of, you don't need the `&` operator in those assignments to `uuid` because the elements of `uuid` are 8 bits so the values will be truncated and only 8 bits will be used. So you can do this:

```
uuid[0] = time_low;
uuid[1] = time_low >> 8;
uuid[2] = time_low >> 16;
uuid[3] = time_low >> 24;

uuid[4] = time_mid;
uuid[5] = time_mid >> 8;

uuid[6] = time_hi_and_version;
uuid[7] = time_hi_and_version >> 8;

uuid[8] = clock_seq_hi_and_res;
uuid[9] = clock_seq_hi_and_res >> 8;

uuid[10] = node;
uuid[11] = node >> 8;
uuid[12] = node >> 16;
uuid[13] = node >> 24;
uuid[14] = node >> 32;
uuid[15] = node >> 40;
```

Answer (score 5):

This code is not correct.  We are returning a pointer to the local variable `uuid`, but that storage is no longer valid when the function has returned, so the pointer *cannot be used* without invoking Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think about that at all (coming from Python and JS this is not something I thought about)!